# How to get the filename where a function is defined in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, swank

I would like to get the name of the file where a particular function or macro definition was last written, for various documentation & testing purposes?

I have posted an answer that works well from me, after the help of PJB on #CommonLisp (IRC.LIBERA.CHAT), but will accept any answers which provide a portable solution that does not depend on SWANK or provides additional detail on how to achieve the same in other IDEs like LispWorks, ACL, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you seek is a *portable* solution – one that is written in portable CL – then the answer to that is to define wrappers for defining forms and then use the wrappers.

```lisp
(defvar *flocs* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

(defgeneric function-location (f/name)
  (:method ((name t))
   (values (gethash name *flocs* nil) t))
  (:method ((f function))
   (multiple-value-bind (le cp nm) (function-lambda-expression f)
     (declare (ignore le cp))
     (if nm
         (function-location nm)
       (values nil nil)))))

(defmacro define-function (f args &body doc/decls/forms)
  (when (or *load-pathname* *compile-file-pathname*)
    ;; Prefer *load-pathname*
    (setf (gethash f *flocs*) (or *load-pathname* *compile-file-pathname*)))
  `(defun ,f ,args ,@doc/decls/forms))
```

In real life you'd call `define-function` `defun` of course, and similarly with `define-variable` etc, and then construct a conduit package for CL which exported all the CL symbols while replacing the defining forms with these ones.

If what you seek is a portable solution in the sense that it exports some standard interface but has varying implementation-dependent backends, then probably looking at what SLY or SWANK do is a good start.  In the case of LW you would want the backend to use DSPECs which are how it deals with location information:

```
> (dspec:dspec-definition-locations '(defun foo))
(((defun foo) :listener))

> (dspec:dspec-definition-locations '(defun needs))
(((defmacro needs)
  #P"..."))

> (defclass foo () ())
#<standard-class foo 402000B763>

> (dspec:name-definition-locations dspec:*dspec-classes* 'foo)
(((defclass foo) :listener) ((defun foo) :listener))
```

Comment: Fantastic answer - thank you!

Answer (score 4):

PJB on #CommonLisp (IRC.LIBERA.CHAT) greatly assisted and provided the below answer (which I have paraphrased so any mistakes are on my end):

Firstly, CL is a lisp-2 (actually, lisp-∞) and thus there may not be a single definition attached to a symbol. For example, which `foo` is being referred to in the below?

```lisp
(deftype foo () (member foo))

(defvar foo 'foo)

(defun foo () foo)
```

In addition, as an example, symbols may be defined in the REPL (no associated filename), so this is not a straightforward question that can be answered without making assumptions on the intent.

Now, when the behaviour of `M-.` is satisfactory for your requirements, you could look in slime/swank what the implementation specific API is to do it.

This should point you to `swank:find-definition-for-emacs`, which may be what you are after:

```lisp
(swank:find-definitions-for-emacs "foo") #| -->

(("#'foo"
 (:location (:file "/private/tmp/foo.lisp")
 (:position 50)
 (:snippet "(defun foo () foo)")))
 
 ("(type foo)"
 (:location (:file "/private/tmp/foo.lisp")
 (:position 1)
 (:snippet "(deftype foo () '(member foo))")))
 
 ("(variable foo)"
 (:location (:file "/private/tmp/foo.lisp")
 (:position 32)
 (:snippet "(defvar foo 'foo)"))))
```

Make sure to load `swank` as a dependency in your `.asd` files if you want to rely on the above.

EDIT: I also found the below very useful (and swank has a similar file for most implementations, so just go through each to see their equivalents):

https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/68c58c0194ff03cd147fcec99f0ee90ba9178875/swank/sbcl.lisp#L811

The function call `(sb-introspect:find-definition-sources-by-name name type)` (name is a symbol, type is a keyword, e.g. :function - refer above link) returns the file in which a definition is stored, assuming you are using SBCL. More (SBCL) details also in:

https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/contrib/sb-introspect/introspect.lisp